# Overflow hidden issue in jQuery vertical slider with popup

Tags: jquery, css, popup, overflow, hidden

I am working on a jQuery Vertical Slider in which I have around 20 thumb images. When I click on the thumb image, a popup appear with image description and detail button. But problem is Vertical slider main container has a css property overflow:hidden; which is not letting popup to appear out of the container.  Please see the following example to understand my issue in a better way.

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/BtAsN/

Following is the example image URL and I want to make my slider look like that.

http://www.thewebmakerz.com/Vertical-Slider.jpg

Please guide me how can I fix that issue. Also if you know any example that work in a same way, please refer.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add html to a page

eg `$('body').append('<div class="imagePopUp"> your content </div>')`

Put this function on your button click event. This way you can dynamically add content outside of your vertical slider and position it where you want.

you can use

```
$('body').removeClass('imagePopUp')
```

do remove it.